# How to get all merge fields of table row using open xml

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to get all merge fields of a table row within a word document .
I used code as below but I am not getting all merge fields-

```
IEnumerable<Table> tables = docGenerated.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Table>();
foreach (Table table in tables)
{
    IEnumerable<TableRow> rows = table.Descendants<TableRow>();
    foreach (TableRow row in rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<TableCell> cells = row.Descendants<TableCell>();
        foreach (TableCell cell in cells)
        {
            foreach (FieldCode field in cell.Descendants<FieldCode>())
            {
                String fieldText = field.Text;
                if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
                {
                    Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                    Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                    String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
                    fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Will the StartsWith call match fields that look like {MERGEFIELD something}, {  Mergefield something  } and so on? Or do you know that your fields always look like { MERGEFIELD something } ?

Comment: i am using multiple merge fields in a cell like - <<mergefield1>><<mergefield2>> etc.

Comment: Ifyouuse alt-F9 in Word,you will see the field coding that Word is actually looking at.If you created the fields via the Word UI and have not edited them,they will start with " MERGEFIELD". But some people enter them manually and omit leading white space, etc.

Comment: I checked them. They all are in perfect format. They all are created via word UI.

Comment: OK, in the XML a field can be represted in one of two ways: smple and complex. Only the complex ones will be picked up using the FieldCode class. To get the other ones, I think you will also need to use the SimpleField class. When you first insert a mergefield field, you will probably get a Simple field. After you do something that will force Word to display the data in the field (such as preview the data), Word will save the field using the more complex representation because that's the only way it can encode the field result. I suggest you look at the XML of a simple example to see this.

Comment: So, there is no stright way to find them using a single type?

Comment: I don't think so. If you need to find mergefield fields in general, you may also need to retrieve more than one w:instrText element from a FieldCode or SimpleField and reconstitute the actual field code from them.